# Using Twitter's typeahead.js - calling my WebAPI, how to fill the drop down list in my typeahead input text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-typeahead

This is my first time using Twitter's `typeahead.js`.  I've got parts of it working, but what's not working is when I type ahead, the drop down list under the input text box is supposed to fill with values, but instead for me it says "undefined".

Here's my client-side code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.typeahead-devs').typeahead({
        name: 'movies',
        remote: {
            url: 'http://localhost:61182/api/SixFilm/GetMovies?term=%QUERY',
            dataType: 'json',
        }
    });
});
```

The URL in the code above works and returns valid JSON.  Here's my UI and my Firebug output:

[image]

I have a feeling I'm getting "undefined" because my "typeahead" doesn't know what to put for the values in the drop down list.  Is there a particular variable I'm missing in my `.typeahead` call?  How would I construct my `typeahead` correctly so that I get values in my drop down list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.  I needed `valueKey`.  `valueKey` in my example is "Name", which is what I want to populate the drop down list:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.typeahead-devs').typeahead({
        name: 'movies',
        remote: {
            url: 'http://localhost:61182/api/SixFilm/GetMovies?term=%QUERY',
            dataType: 'json',
        }
        valueKey: "Name",
    });
});
```

[image]